# How to create higher order components in Angular 2

Tags: angular

Higher Order Components (HOC) is a pattern common among React community. See [this article](https://medium.com/@franleplant/react-higher-order-components-in-depth-cf9032ee6c3e#.m111af95l) if you don't know what's a HOC

Do they make sense in Angular 2?
How to make a HOC?
Any examples?

Comment: Maybe these can help: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/dynamic-form.html, http://mean.expert/2016/05/14/angular-2-container-component/

Comment: The question in its current state requires to have a good understanding of both React and Angular 2. Explaining what exactly you want to do without using HOC term will increase the chances to get a quality answer.

Comment: I think that in Angular you can extend the component and make other template, so you can easily achieve common behavior to different components UI

Answer (score 5):

Use [NgComponentOutlet](https://angular.io/api/common/NgComponentOutlet)

Simple case

```
@Component({selector: 'hello-world', template: 'Hello World!'})
class HelloWorld {
}

@Component({
  selector: 'ng-component-outlet-simple-example',
  template: `<ng-container *ngComponentOutlet="myComponent"></ng-container>`
})
class NgTemplateOutletSimpleExample {
  // This field is necessary to expose HelloWorld to the template.
  myComponent= HelloWorld;
}
```

Advanced cases including providing Injector and Content are available in [official documentation](https://angular.io/api/common/NgComponentOutlet)

Answer (score 2):

I am also very interested in something similar to HOC (Recompose like in Angular 2). I recently was trying to create an analog to mapToProps HOC' Recompose for Angular - mapToInputs using Angular structural directive. I am looking for a better approach.

```
  @Component({
    selector: 'user-list',
    template: `
       <h2>{{status}} users</h2> 
       <div *ngFor="let item of data">{{item}}</div>
    `
  })
  export class UserList {
    @Input() data: Array<any>;
    @Input() status: string;
  }

  @Directive({selector: '[mapInputs]'})
  export class MapInputs {
    component;

    @Input() set mapInputsComponent(component) {
     this.component = component;
    }

    @Input() set mapInputs(fn) {
      this.vc.clear();
      let factory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(this.component);
      let componetRef =  this.vc.createComponent(factory);

      let inputs = fn();
      console.log(inputs);
      Object.entries(inputs).forEach(([key, value]) => {
        componetRef.instance[key] = value;
      });
    }

    constructor(private vc: ViewContainerRef, 
          private componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver) {
    }
  }

  @Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `
      <div>
        <button (click)="doubledata()">Doubel Data</button>
        <div *mapInputs="filterBy.bind(null, {data:data, status:'active'}); component: component"></div>
        <div *mapInputs="filterBy.bind(null, {data:data, status:'passive'}); component: component"></div>
        <div *mapInputs="filterBy.bind(null,  {data:data, status:'blocked'}); component: component"></div>
      </div>
    `,
  })
  export class App {
    name: string;
    component = UserList;
    data = ['active', 'active', 'passive', 'blocked', 'blocked'];
    filterBy = (context) => {
       return {
          status: context.status,
          data: context.data.filter(el => el ===  context.status);
       };
    }

    doubledata(){
      this.data = this.data.concat(this.data);
    }

    constructor() {
      this.name = `Angular! v${VERSION.full}`
    }
  }
```

Comment: It looks like a decent approach. It seems like Angular doesn't allow you to "naturally" do that... Are you using this approach for yourself Julia?

Comment: here are two two types of HOC. Proxy props HOC are possible to create with angular but Inheritance Inversion - i have no idea how to do it with angular with AOT. I just really like idea of HOC in react and miss it in angular.

Comment: @JuliaPassynkova its completely possible with IVY https://medium.com/angular-in-depth/all-you-need-to-know-about-ivy-the-new-angular-engine-9cde471f42cf